# Can not add WSDL

Tags: wsdl, definition

I have a problem when I try to add a WDSL to my repository. In order to explain my problem, those are steps I followed :

- I created a service "test" in version 1.0.0 (service namespace = "common")
- I added this service to my repository
- I added a schema "test0.xsd" with a namespace "http://datamodel.etab.test.fr" in version 1.0.0

When I try to add finally a WSDL with this definition :

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://ged.bo.test.fr/" 
      xmlns:testged="http://datamodel.ged.bo.test.fr/" 
      xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
      xmlns:tns="http://ged.bo.test.fr/" 
      xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" 
      xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
      xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/">"
```

I get the following error :

> "Unable to upload file File upload failed. Failed to add resource
>   /_system/governance/trunk/wsdls/@{namespace}/1.0.0/TestGedService.wsdl. Invalid WSDL definition found"

I do not know at all where is the error(s) and why I have this message.

Comment: It seems I have this kind of problem when I try to add a file which have at least one dependence...

Comment: When I add a XSD file which has no dependence, it is added. When I try to add a XSD file which has a dependence to the previous one (with an include clause), I have a similar error... :(